# how to return missing row based on column, where other values match in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't even know how to ask this so I can google, so my apologies in advance.
I have a SQL table where it looks something like this

```
col1 col2 col3
a    1    name1
a    2    name1
a    3    name1
a    4    name1
b    1    name1
b    2    name1
b    3    name1
```

If you notice, there are 4 rows for col1=a for each col2 value[1-4]. There is NOT, however, a record where col1=b and col2=4.

With grouping and count<4 I can return rows that exist, but how can I return something like `'b,4,name1'` for a row (my missing record)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT T.COL1, T.COL3, COUNT(T.COL2) COL2_COUNT, STRING_AGG(T.COL2,',') COL2_LIST
FROM
(
SELECT F.COL1, F.COL3, F.COL2 FROM TBL F 
) T
GROUP BY T.COL1, T.COL3
) J WHERE J.COL2_COUNT < 4
```

Comment: Provide the query that you have tried so far and also provide the desire output data

Comment: There are a lot of records in this table, so I would prefer not to join against the same table over 4x if possible

Comment: I added some what my current sql looks like. if I have 4 total distinct values for col2, there should then be a respective record for for each of those values where all other fields match. Does that make sense? I can return a list of col2 values that found a match, but i only want to see col2 value where there was no match.

Comment: is it always the last number that is missing ? Or you will have case like `1  -  4` and 2 & 3 is missing?

Comment: It is the latter. So 2&3 can be missing, or 2,3,&4 can be missing.

Comment: So all unique col1&col3 values are expected to have col2 values sequentially from 1 to number of  distinct col2 values in the entire table. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to create a cross join and then filter out what is missing by testing for filter.col1 is null.

**Schema (MSSQL 2019)**

```
   
   
   CREATE TABLE raw
       ([col1] varchar(1), [col2] int, [col3] varchar(5))
   ;
       
   INSERT INTO raw
       ([col1], [col2], [col3])
   VALUES
       ('a', 1, 'name1'),
       ('a', 2, 'name1'),
       ('a', 3, 'name1'),
       ('a', 4, 'name1'),
       ('b', 1, 'name1'),
       ('b', 2, 'name1'),
       ('b', 3, 'name1')
   ;
```

**SQL Query**

```
    -- insert into raw -- uncomment to create missing records.
    select candidate_base.* from ( 
      select candidate.col1, base.col2, base.col3 from 
     ( select col1 from raw group by col1 ) candidate ,
     ( select col2, col3 from raw group by col2, col3 ) base
     ) candidate_base
     left join raw filter
     on  candidate_base.col1 = filter.col1
     and candidate_base.col2 = filter.col2
     and candidate_base.col3 = filter.col3
     where filter.col1 is null 

     GO
```

```
 col1 | col2 | col3 
 :--- | ---: | :----
 b    |    4 | name1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=471811bc11767784e40bec8767c0ecfa)*

Comment: Thanks for this. It was past midnight when I was trying to get this done. Not sure why I didn't just use a pivot table, but that's what I did and it gives similar desired results.